# How to change datacontext for DataGridComboBoxColumn to a specific class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm totally new at WPF and I'm stuck with the bellow situation:

```
 class Person{
    string Name;
    List<Address> ListAddresses;
 }
```

I have a DataGrid with ItemsSource as an `ObservableCollection<Person>`. This collection is in `MainViewModel` class.

I want to create a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with the addresses.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>   
      <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListAddresses, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
         AncestorType={x:Type local:Person}}}">
      </DataGridComboBoxColumn>      
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I receive the following error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference
>   'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='PersonApp.UL.ViewModels.Person', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ListAddresses; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=11440639); target property is
>   'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: You mention `MainViewModel`, so you're using the MVVM structure?

Comment: Yes. I am using MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridComboBoxColumn` is going to cause you many problems. Try this:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Something"
                            SortMemberPath="[SelectedAddress].[property from Address class]">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListAddresses}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAddress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          SelectedValuePath="[SelectedAddress].[property from Address class]"
                          DisplayMemberPath="[property from Address class (like Name)]" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

You should also include `SelectedAddress` property in your `Person` class, to store which `Address` is selected in the `ComboBox`.

Binding to property that is inside your `ItemsSource` scope (which in this case is what you bind to `DataGrid`) does not require `RelativeSource` binding, that's why you are getting an error. `RelativeSource` is required in case you set your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to for example `PeopleList` and you want to bind your (that is inside this `DataGrid`) `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to a property that is in your `ViewModel`, but NOT inside your `PeopleList`.

Another thing for binding to `ComboBox` is if you bind `ItemsSource` to a collection of objects other than `strings`, you have to set `DisplayMemberPath` to a property in your object, in order to make the control display the right caption. So for example if you are binding object `Car` and it has a `string` type property called `Name`, you should set `DisplayMemberPath` to `Name` in order to make your control display list of `Car.Names` (selecting one will still result in selecting the whole object, not just the `Name` property).

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you a lot for the detailed and quickly answer!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Also if you need binding to ancestor, you should rather try finding an ancestor by control type, not by object from `ViewModel` type. For example if you have a `View` which is an `UserControl` and it has a `DataGrid` inside it, then you should look for ancestor of type `{x:Type UserControl}`. This will give you the `DataContext` of your `UserControl`, which (if you implement MVVM correctly) is your `ViewModel` bound to your `UserControl`.